# accessing data from another viewController returns (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass data to another string in another viewController, but it keeps returning (null). i've checked that

```
[indexNo valueForKey:@"id"]
```

returns a value and it does, but when i try to pass this data to storeID string in another viewcontroller it returns (null). How come is this?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        indexNo = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        indexNo = [storesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    StoreViewController *svc = [[StoreViewController alloc] init];
    svc.storeID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[indexNo valueForKey:@"id"]];



}
```

Comment: Where are you checking that it's null? Is it null where you're setting svc.storeID in the above code or sometime later?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the view controller `svc` in the code you've provided. Did you mean to push it on to a navigation controller?

Comment: i'm checking it in storeViewController where i'm logging it in viewdidload

Comment: Where are you creating your controllers? How do you navigate from the controller with your posted code to the StoreViewController?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` will get called when you do something with the view controller` like add it to a navigation controller's stack or present it... you're not doing either of those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very little information here to go off, but at first glance you need to add the view controller to the view hierarchy in order for `-viewDidLoad` etc... to fire. Try doing this to present it modally:

```
StoreViewController *svc = [[StoreViewController alloc] init];
svc.storeID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[indexNo valueForKey:@"id"]];

// present it modally 
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or push it on to your navigation controller (if you're using one).